# regular expression to ckeck if multiple patterns exitst in list

Tags: python, regex

```
l = ['abc_123','abc_456','ade_098','def_765','deg_432']

patterns=['a.*3','def.*']
```

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that simultaneously checks if both patterns in `patterns` exist in list `l`.
In the example above, this is true because '`abc_123`' and '`def_765`' match each of the patterns in `patterns`. I thought of

```
[s for s in l if ((re.match(patterns[0], s)) or (re.match(patterns[1], s)))]
```

but what should I do if I have a list like the following?

```
l = ['abc_123','abc_456','ade_093','deh_765','deg_432']
```

In this example, the code above will give me two results but only the pattern '`a.*3`' is matched.

Ideally I would like to return True if both patterns are matched and False otherwise.

I can do something like

```
pat0 = [s for s in l if re.match(patterns[0], s)]
pat1 = [s for s in l if re.match(patterns[1], s)]
```

and check if both `pat0` and `pat1` are not empty, but this seems kind of wasteful, especially if my lists are long and there are several patterns.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. You have got too many brackets.

Comment: @OctopuSS7 which code doesn't work? I just copy-pasted the code above and it works

Comment: `[s for s in l if ((re.match(patterns[0], s)) or (re.match(patterns[1], s)))]` You have more open brackets than close brackets. Maybe it works in the context of your code, but on it's own, that doesn't work.

Comment: Look in my answer for the corrected code, with the right bracketing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
>>> patterns=['a.*3','def.*']
>>> 
>>> l1 = ['abc_123','abc_456','ade_098','def_765','deg_432']
>>> all((any(re.match(p,s) for s in l1) for p in patterns))
True # b/c 'a.*3' matches 'abc_123' AND 'def.*' matches def_765
>>>
>>> l2 = ['abc_123','abc_456','ade_093','deh_765','deg_432']
>>> all((any(re.match(p,s) for s in l2) for p in patterns))
False # b/c 'a.*3' matches 'abc_123' BUT there is not match for 'def.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic boolean logic. You are using `or`. That returns true if either are true. You need `and`, which only returns true if both are ture, or if both conditions are matched in your case.

Your final code would be `[s for s in l if ((re.match(patterns[0], s)) and (re.match(patterns[1], s))]`